# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: getview, android, java

В чем ошибка?

Приложение выводит некоторые данные, подгруженные из интернета списком. Данные подгружаются с помощью AsynkTask.

Если кликнуть по одному из элементов списка, который является группой, то подгрузиться список для данной группы.

Так вот, сама проблема: кликаю по группе, возвращаюсь назад, опять кликаю по группе и тут вылезает вот такой эксепшен:

```
02-25 09:29:52.436: E/AndroidRuntime(311): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-25 09:29:52.455: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class default.MyActivity$ItemAdapter)]
```

Как это дело решить?

===========================================

```
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    protected ProgressDialog proDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        proDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        proDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        proDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        proDialog.setCancelable(true);
        proDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        rsj = new ReadStringJson(SERVER_URL + SERVER_PATH_1 + "from=" + (from+1) + "&number=" + number + SERVER_PATH_2 + GROUP);

        try {
            parsingData(rsj.readFromServer());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             Log.e("IOException: ", ex.toString());
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
             Log.e("JSONException: ", ex.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        adapter.addEnginesNames(names);
        adapter.addEnginesDescriptions(descriptions);
        adapter.addEnginesLogoUrl(logoUrl);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        proDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

---

```
    class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    protected ProgressDialog proDialog;
    private ArrayList<String> enginesNames;
    private ArrayList<String> enginesDescriptions;
    private ArrayList<String> enginesLogoUrl;

    public ArrayList<String> addEnginesNames(ArrayList<String> newNames) {
        enginesNames = newNames;
        return enginesNames;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> addEnginesDescriptions(
            ArrayList<String> newDescriptions) {
        enginesDescriptions = newDescriptions;
        return enginesDescriptions;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> addEnginesLogoUrl(ArrayList<String> newLogoUrl) {
        enginesLogoUrl = newLogoUrl;
        return enginesLogoUrl;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView text1;
        public TextView text2;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (logoUrl == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return logoUrl.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(EngineBrowseByOnline.this);

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .memoryCacheExtraOptions(100, 100)
                .threadPoolSize(5)
                .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 2)
                .offOutOfMemoryHandling()
                .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
                .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
                .discCacheFileCount(100)
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()).enableLogging()
                .build();

        imageLoader.init(config);

        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.text1.setText(enginesNames.get(position));
        holder.text2.setText(enginesDescriptions.get(position));

        imageLoader.displayImage(enginesLogoUrl.get(position),
                holder.image, options);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() вызываешь после закачки группы?

Comment: После подгрузки и парсинга json в doInBackground вызывают notifyDataSetChanged() в onPostExecute

Comment: покажи лучше код, что то там у тебя напутано )

Comment: и адаптер покажи

Comment: использую адаптер библиотеки UniversalImageLoader

Comment: Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread!!
вместо изменения содержимого адаптера напрямую нужно его изменять в главном потоке!
runOnUIThread()

Comment: @metalurgus, а можете на примере показать

Answer (score 1):

Не делай так!

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

Создавай ImageLoader во внешнем классе, а не при каждом получении вьюхи.

А по поводу вопроса...
Такая ошибка возникает если ты меняешь список или курсор, который используется адаптером где-то во внешнем коде, а не в самом адаптере. Так тоже не делай!
Ну или по крайней мере все что тебе нужно это вызывать для этого в AsyncTask adapter.add(element)

Comment: По поводу создания imageloader - взял с примера автора библиотеки... Совет учту.
А можете по-подробнее где про список? где его вызывать?